# execute repo command for some of the repositories

Tags: git, repository

Is there any way I can run repo command for some of the repos and not all?? Like suppose I have 20 repos in my tree and I want to run one command for only 10 repositories, is it possible using repo command??
take one simple example :

repo forall -c git gc

This command will run git gc in all repositories.What if I don't want to run this command for all repos? Is there any way other that going into each repo and running git command manually, to do this?

Answer (score 3):

"repo help forall" answers your question:

```
Usage: repo forall [<project>...] -c <command> [<arg>...]
```

Simply list the project you want the command to be executed on before the command itself.
Something like:

```
repo forall project1 project2 -c git log -n 1
```

work for me.

Comment: Thank you...!! But it will be difficult to mention project names explicitly if you have more than 300 projects in your tree for which you want to run commands..